# Does Apache camel cdi work with Tomcat?

Tags: apache-camel, apache-camel-cdi

Does Apache camel-cdi work with Tomcat/TomEE? I have tried using TomEE but camel context was not started. If not then which container we need to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

camel-cdi works with TomEE in recent releases (early ones were not that portable).

This post https://blog-rmannibucau.rhcloud.com/#/post/camel-cdi-fatjar for instance shows how to use it even in embedded mode.

Can your issue be your application is not scanned due to tomee scanning rules?